# ASP.NET MVC How to use Ajax.BeginForm?

Tags: asp.net, ajax, asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-ajax, ajax.beginform

i try to use Asp.net mvc4 Ajax helper and when i submit form it makes full post back.

Notice that i include all important scripts like Jquery and jquery.unobtrusive-ajax inside head element.

```
   <script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery.unobtrusive-ajax.min.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
   <script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery-1.9.1.min.js")" type="text/javascript">    </script>
```

**Students Controller**

```
 [HttpPost]
    public string Create(Students students)
    {
        if (Request.IsAjaxRequest())
        {
            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                db.Students.Add(students);
                db.SaveChanges();
                // return RedirectToAction("Index");
            }
        }

        return "<h2>Customer updated successfully!</h2>";
    }
```

**Create View**

```
@using (Ajax.BeginForm("Create","Students", new AjaxOptions() { HttpMethod= "POST",     UpdateTargetId = "fs1" }))
{

<fieldset id="fs1">
    <legend>Students</legend>

    <div class="editor-label">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.ST_NAME)
    </div>
    <div class="editor-field">
        @Html.EditorFor(model => model.ST_NAME)
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.ST_NAME)
    </div>

    <div class="editor-label">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.ST_BIRTH_DATE)
    </div>
    <div class="editor-field">
        @Html.EditorFor(model => model.ST_BIRTH_DATE)
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.ST_BIRTH_DATE)
    </div>

    <div class="editor-label">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.ST_PHONE)
    </div>
    <div class="editor-field">
        @Html.EditorFor(model => model.ST_PHONE)
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.ST_PHONE)
    </div>

    <div class="editor-label">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.ST_ADDR)
    </div>
    <div class="editor-field">
        @Html.EditorFor(model => model.ST_ADDR)
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.ST_ADDR)
    </div>

    <div class="editor-label">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.ST_CLASS)
    </div>
    <div class="editor-field">
        @Html.EditorFor(model => model.ST_CLASS)
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.ST_CLASS)
    </div>

    <div class="editor-label">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.ST_STAT)
    </div>
    <div class="editor-field">
        @Html.EditorFor(model => model.ST_STAT)
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.ST_STAT)
    </div>

    <div class="editor-label">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.LAST_UPDATE_DATE)
    </div>
    <div class="editor-field">
        @Html.EditorFor(model => model.LAST_UPDATE_DATE)
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.LAST_UPDATE_DATE)
    </div>

    <div class="editor-label">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.CURRENT_CLASS_GRADE)
    </div>
    <div class="editor-field">
        @Html.EditorFor(model => model.CURRENT_CLASS_GRADE)
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.CURRENT_CLASS_GRADE)
    </div>

    <div class="editor-label">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.CURRENT_CLASS)
    </div>
    <div class="editor-field">
        @Html.EditorFor(model => model.CURRENT_CLASS)
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.CURRENT_CLASS)
    </div>

    <div class="editor-label">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.ST_CODE)
    </div>
    <div class="editor-field">
        @Html.EditorFor(model => model.ST_CODE)
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.ST_CODE)
    </div>

    <div class="editor-label">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.REG_CLASS)
    </div>
    <div class="editor-field">
        @Html.EditorFor(model => model.REG_CLASS)
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.REG_CLASS)
    </div>

    <div class="editor-label">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.IDNO)
    </div>
    <div class="editor-field">
        @Html.EditorFor(model => model.IDNO)
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.IDNO)
    </div>

    <p>
        <input type="submit" value="Create" />
    </p>
</fieldset>
}
```

Notice that when i check if the request is ajax it gave me false.

Comment: Have you tried flipping the order you load javascript? Scripts are loaded synchronously so jquery should be defined prior to the unobtrusive ajax

Comment: Thank's SeanCarroll it worked :)